Managing multiple interdependent git repositories - unification vs symbolic links
Up until today, I was able to manage seven repositories using a single view of the Source Control tab of VS Code.
Basically, I have 6 embedded firmware projects that run on different platforms, each in their own repository.
I then have a single shared repository where I keep all of the header files/drivers that are shared by all of these projects.
Each project repository contains a symbolic link to the place where  the shared repository is cloned on  my local machine so that the application structure is like:

Application

Symlink to shared repository



symlink in folder tree
Today when I opened up VS code, I see that this is no longer working.
I used to be able to force VS code to "add the repository" to the source control view using Git Graph: Add Git Repository...  but that now throws errors:
The folder "c:/PARTICLE_LOCAL/jaza_embedded" is not within the opened Visual Studio Code workspace, and therefore could not be added to Git Graph.
I can get the symlinked repo to show up in the source code management tab if I manually add the local folder to the workspace though:
shared folder added to vs code workspace redundantly at workspace root
both repositories now showing in Git management tab
I tried:

Checking if any extensions got updated in the past few days that could be causing this issue, and rolled back to previous versions of extensions
Checked that VS code itself did not have any updates recently

I expected:

To find that some recent change to VS Code or its extensions has caused this to stop working.

What resulted:

Could not find any cause of this new problem

What I am considering and would like help with:
I am considering unifying all of these git repositories into a single one, since I need the shared portions of the repositories to be the same for each project in the repo whenever I am compiling.  My concern is about how to do this, and what "gotchas" or downsides there are in unifying 7 repositories into a single one.


Even though using git via VSCode could bring some extra comfort, you don't have to do it. You can use any different client or the command line. It will dismiss all the issues with the scope of VSCode workspace. 2. I hope your "c:/PARTICLE_LOCAL/jaza_embedded" is not out of your git repository, is that right? If it is out of this repository... just don't do such things.


So, I have 4 repositories that all depend on some shared code in a 5th repository (jaza_embedded).  My strategy to manage that has been to clone all 5 repositories and add symbolic links in the 4 repositories to the 5th repository.  Is that what you are saying I should not do?  What is a better alternative?  Git submodules?

4 repositories cloned together? No, this is not reliable. Everything should be self-contained. How get git work with a symbolic link outside a repository?
However, git can work across repositories, but in a different way — see git submodules. Or git subtrees.

I have looked at both Git subtrees and submodules, however this is not a solution that works for me because when I want to make a change to one of the shared files, i either need to make that change to each version of the shared files in each of the two repos using submodules, or else push the changes upstream to the shared repo from repo A, and then sync them back down to repo B.  The only possible workaround I have thought of that doesn't involve symbolic links is to merge all the repos into a single repo, in which case the shared files can just live in that same repo... i like that

It looks like you can get into a big abuse and mess. The entire situation looks insane. After all, did you think about creation of a new repository out of 4 and get out of all that? After your previous comment, this is the only possibility I can see.

Look, after some thinking, I found that I can lay out mathematically string proofs of some points. First of all, all those POSIX hard links, symlinks, reparse points cannot bring any changes to your problem in principle, no matter how well they are implemented in git. Also, I could lay out some tentative development plan, but it involves permanent or temporary (never late to rethink) creation of new united repository out of merged clones of 4 repositories. Please think if you want me to spend time on explaining all that.

Hey thanks for the offer, that's very gracious of you.  I think going the route of merging all of these repositories into a single one is the only solution that makes sense, especially now that my team is growing and there are now multiple contributors to the repo(s),  Is the process described here the one to go with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

“....is the only solution that makes sense...” Tom, thank you for understanding.  I upvoted your question. As it was my initiative to suggest this sort of approach, what if I post it as a formal answer? Will you consider accepting it formally? I promise to add some pieces of advice on how you can proceed with the development of the repositories in stages, to reserve the possibility to rethink later, and what to do with POSIX links (basically, nothing, but I explain why). I am asking about it only because I can see that many tend to crack down on opinions, lack of source code..., etc.

As to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories: no, but in a simpler way. You don't have git subtree anyway. You need to clone all 4 repositories locally side by side, and review it all to make sure all builds and works together. Then create a brand-new repository and commit united code there. Don't modify any existing repository. I can explain why in an answer...

Hey @SergeyAKryukov, I would love you to submit a formal answer to this, I will definitely consider accepting it!  My main concerns with unifying all repos into a single new repo is that it will basically be like a blank slate git history wise.  This will make it very hard to compare changes moving forward against versions of source code from the projects from before the unification of the repos, right?

— “I would love you to submit a formal answer to this”. Thank you for your reply. Sure thing, only it will take some time. And I also want to check on POSIX links on a GitHub, I have a special test GitHub repository for all experiments at SAKryukov.

— Okay, I've submitted the formal answer.

First, I've tested git operations with POSIX symlinks. They work if the appropriate option is available (git config core.symlinks true, git config --get core.symlinks to test it). The symlinks between files work immediately, but for symlinks between directories, git requires configuration of submodules. So far, so good.
It's good that you've come to the same conclusion as I did: merging all of these repositories into a single one is the only solution that makes sense. Anyway, let's overview the situation with the POSIX symlink. Basically, hardlinks, symlinks, and NTFS junctions (reparse points) are associations between the file system objects (files or directories, it does not matter) that make that object graph an arbitrary graph, not necessarily a tree (a tree is a graph without loops). From the revision control system standpoint, it makes no essential difference between the pure-tree set of file system objects and arbitrary graphs. Why?
This is because a git repository always works with a set of file system objects of the same file system, and this is quite a reasonable approach. Only then the repository clone can be placed at any point of a local file system without losing any dependencies. Yes, git can refer to foreign repositories, but this is done through URL references, because different repositories, strictly speaking, are technically independent. POSIX links between different repositories would not make any sense, because cloning two different repositories at arbitrary locations would break those links anyway. All the above is a schematic proof of this fact, but it can be proven in a much stricter way.
You also need to take into account your practical reason: you require the possibility to modify files on all the repositories of the solution.
So, let's talk about merging the repositories into one. The first important key (#1) is to create a brand-new git repository. Another key (#2) is that you need to plan the migration and the development in two or more stages, it is important to keep the possibility to retreat your steps and rethink the general design. Let's assume you have four already functioning repositories, A, B, C, and D. The tentative steps may look like this:

Clone the repositories to a local file system A, B, C, and D side by side. Let's say, you have the common local directory U with A, B, C, and D inside it.
Remove all .git directories.
Create a brand-new git repository on the server.
Clone the newly created empty (or almost empty) repository to the local file system, say, N (new).
Move A, B, C, and D from U into N.
Commit changes in N, and push the result to the server.
Make a first tag for N (a new repository) and push it to the server with the tag.
The first stage of the development is complete. In the general case, the new directory contains some code, which is not yet operational.
Here is the next key (#3): you did not modify 4 existing repositories.
Make the code operational by adding missing links between A, B, C, and D. Here is another key (#4): better use relative paths, not POSIX links, no matter how well they are supported by git.
A short note on POSIX links: people usually used them in the programming system where working with relative links looked cumbersome. I saw them only in pretty old C/C++ projects, mostly on *NIX. There is nothing wrong with this approach, but it would be some unnecessary complication. No matter — you decide, the key #4 is just advice.
After the final commit of the operational code, the second stage is complete. Make a tag at this point.
Continue development on N until the software is stable. Change all parts of the new repository arbitrarily.
At a certain stable point, decide that this third stage is complete, and tag it.
Now you have options for the fourth stage. Based on your new understanding of the state of the new project, you can get to the next step of development in two ways: 1) You can continue development in the new repository (cloned to N) and forget A, B, C, D. 2) You can decide that the former A, B, C, D parts are stable enough, or some subset of this 4 repositories is stable enough, so you can refactor the code so to make them independent again; at this point, you can start submitting the changes into some or all of these independent repositories.

This is a quick sketch. Please comment if I missed something, then I would be able to modify or add something.

Thanks Sergey.  That all makes sense to me.  I think the key takeaways are:
#1) Avoid symbolic links wherever possible (prefer relative links, which are portable as long as all the repos are unified into a single one)
#2) Create a new repository to unify all of the other ones together, and do development within this repository
#3) If/when situation arises where I need to look at changes in the unified repo vs very old code from the "independent days", I can copy/paste the changes back into the independent repo to evaluate the diffs.

@Tom MacDonald: Thank you for your note and for accepting the answer. I hope you can develop this stuff successfully along these lines, or in similar ways.

@Tom MacDonald — “...prefer relative links, which are portable...” Oh, yes, thank you. I should have pointed out but missed the point that those POSIX links, in general case, are not portable. Say, if you create a single link target file and a symlink to it in one directory, and then you could be tempted to copy these two files or the entire containing directory into another location, as you need such moves all the time. But no, it won't work, the relationship between the two will be lost in the copy. Worst, most file managers won't show the problem, it will remain subliminal.
